# AppLocalizations localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked

Tags: flutter, localization

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
AppLocalizations localizations =AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
```

I am using this line under builder, it was working and everything was fine but suddenly I got this error and I could not fix it.

````
Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...
.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart:490:14: Error: 'of' is already declared in this scope.
  String get of;
             ^^
.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart:67:28: Context: Previous declaration of 'of'.
  static AppLocalizations? of(BuildContext context) {
                           ^^
lib/screens/main-page/components/appbar.dart:25:55: Error: Can't use 'of' because it is declared more than once.
    AppLocalizations localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
                                                      ^^
lib/screens/shared_components/mskn_drawer.dart:18:55: Error: Can't use 'of' because it is declared more than once.
    AppLocalizations localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
                                                      ^^
lib/screens/main-page/components/search_field.dart:18:55: Error: Can't use 'of' because it is declared more than once.
    AppLocalizations localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
                                                      ^^
lib/screens/main-page/components/suggestion_list.dart:26:55: Error: Can't use 'of' because it is declared more than once.
    AppLocalizations localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
                                                      ^^
lib/screens/other/about_us.dart:16:55: Error: Can't use 'of' because it is declared more than once.
    AppLocalizations localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
                                                      ^^
lib/screens/other/connect_with_us.dart:19:55: Error: Can't use 'of' because it is declared more than once.
    AppLocalizations localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
                                                      ^^
lib/screens/main-page/components/buildings_cards.dart:23:55: Error: Can't use 'of' because it is declared more than once.
    AppLocalizations localizations = AppLocalizations.of(context)!;
   
```                                                    ^^
````

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a little bit too late for the answer, but the problem is that you declared a variable called "of" in the app localizations file, but flutter already utilizes "of" so it can't distinct between one and another.

Solution: change the name of that variable "of" to "ofText", for example.

Comment: Yes, it was it.